# Using ajax response as the function's argument

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, google-visualization

I'm trying to use the ajax response as an argument for the function drawing the chart with google charts.

This is the JS code:

```
data.addRows([['One', 5], ['Two', 2]]);
```

As you can see, the argument contains a couple of square brackets with the "chart's unit" name and its value. Everything works. However when I pass ajax responseText as the argument, it doesn't work at all.

```
data.addRows(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

The PHP code returns json_encode($value), where the $value variable is this string:
[[one, 5], [two, 2]]

So as the result I get:

```
"[['one', 5], ['two', 2]]"
```

BTW. I also tried removing double quotes from the string in the JS code - still no results.

What's wrong? The firebug gives me some strange errors: Argument given to addRows must be either a number or an array...

How should I fix this?

Comment: what do you get if you console.log(xmlhttp.repsonseText); ?

Comment: It seems the result needs to be transformed into an object first. I would look for a JSON parser to convert the result before feeding into the `addRows()` function.

Comment: I've used json_encode(), shouldn't this be enough? Alerting response gives me the proper string, the same string works when I use it as an argument.

Comment: console.log? It just gives me an error...somewhere in the google code: "if (!utl.isIE()) {" here.

Comment: Well as said above it is probably because it is just a string to javaScript. Try using data.addRows(JSON.parse(xmlhttp.repsonseText));

Comment: Well, it gives me "JSON.parse: unexpected character", both with json_encode() and without it.

Answer (score 3):

`data.addRows` is expecting a real JavaScript array, and you're passing it a string. In order to convert the string to an array, you should use a JSON parser. However, the response you're getting from your server is not valid JSON due to the single quotes.

Steps:

1. Update your server to send a valid JSON response which includes sending the [correct mime type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type) `application/json`. Following standards is helpful if you use an ajax library like jQuery which can do the JSON parsing for you.
2. Parse the `responseText` yourself using something like `JSON.parse(...)` or use an ajax library like jQuery to do it for you. Either way, you need to convert the `responseText` string to a real JavaScript array.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do `data.addRows(JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText));`. However, the single quotes are going to give you problems and so you need to somehow tell PHP to use double quotes for the keys.

You *could* do something like `data.addRows(JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText.replace(/'/, "\"")))`;`, but it would be far better to make sure that PHP uses the right quotes.